# A variety in $\Bbb A^2$ isomorphic to $\Bbb A^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The question I am trying to solve is this:

> Let $f\in k[t_1]$ be a non constant polynomial. Show that $X := V(t_2−f) \subset \mathbb{A}^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

I am new to algebraic geometry. The solution I have written is:

$X = \{(t_1, f(t_1))\}$

Define a map $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1 \rightarrow X$ such that $\phi(t_1) = (t_1, f(t_1))$

Since $\phi$ is an isomorphism, $\mathbb{A}^1$ and X are isomorphic.

Is this solution correct? Is my isomorphism actually an isomorphism or am I confused? Can any bijective mapping between $\mathbb{A}^1$ and $X$ be termed an isomorphism?

Comment: If you're not sure that your functions are well-defined morphisms of varieties you can always convert the statement you'd like to show into one that's algebraic. By definition, $X$ is affine with coordinate ring $k[t_1,t_2]/(t_2-f)$, so we can define $k[t_1,t_2] \to k[t_1]$ by $t_1 \mapsto t_1$ and $t_2 \mapsto f$. It is easy to see that the kernel of this map is $t_2-f$, so your $\phi$ is an isomorphism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sets $X$ and $\mathbb{A}^1$ are affine varieties, so you need to prove that your function is an isomorphism of affine varieties.

Showing it is a bijection is almost given by definition. So what is left is to show that it is a morphism of affine varieties with an inverse function, which is also a morphism of affine varieties.

Your function is clearly a morphism, since it is polynomial in its entries. So now we need to find the inverse, and show that that too is a morphism. Viewing $X$ as a subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^2$, we can describe $X$ as a subset of that. So to describe the inverse function, we just need to describe it in coordinates. A natural guess would just be to project onto the "x-axis", by defining

$\psi : X \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^1$

by $\psi(a,b)=a$. This is clearly a morphism, and I leave it you to check that it is indeed the inverse function to $\phi$.

N.B. I'm pretty sure you could let $f$ be any polynomial, the restrictions don't seem to be needed.